# How do I prevent openpyxl from inserting an "@" when using summed array formulae in the cell?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

When attempting a particular formula in openpyxl I'm encountering a peculiar behavior.

```
import openpyxl as xl

test    = xl.Workbook()
sheet   = test.active
sheet.title = 'Test'

year = 2014
pct  = .02
for col in range(1, 12):
    sheet.cell(row = 1, column = col).value = year
    sheet.cell(row = 2, column = col).value = pct
    sheet.cell(row = 2, column = col).number_format = '0.00%'
    if col % 2 == 1:
        pct += .01
    if col % 2 == 0:
        year += 1

for row in reversed(range(4, year - 2009)):
    sheet.cell(row = row, column = 1).value = year
    sheet.cell(row = row, column = 2).value = '=PRODUCT(1+TRANSPOSE($A$1:$K$1=$A' + str(row) + ')*TRANSPOSE($A$2:$K$2))-1'
    sheet.cell(row = row, column = 2).number_format = '0.00%'
    year -= 1

test.save('test.xlsx')
```

When opening the resulting file, Excel places an "@" in front of all cell ranges, even though the function evaluates correctly when you remove them. In other words, when I use CTRL+H to remove the "@"'s I get the result I want, and as you can see above, I did not code the "@"'s to be there. How can I prevent openpyxl/Excel from inserting the "@"'s?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: There's a few questions here on SO already dealing with this, though I'm not sure if any has a foolproof answer yet.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any, maybe I just need some better Google-Fu then...

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=openpyxl+formula+at+sign+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: The solution listed in the above link was not working for me. I will be posting the solution that did work for me. Thanks for the help BigBen!

Answer (score 1):

`sheet.cell(row = row, column = 2).value = xl_formula.ArrayFormula('B'+ str(row), '=PRODUCT(1+TRANSPOSE($A$1:$K$1=$A' + str(row) + ')*TRANSPOSE($A$2:$K$2))-1')`

Was the solution that worked for me. Bread crumbs were laid by BigBen. Thanks again for the help!