# remove "@" on formula before hyperlink

Tags: python-3.x, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

I currently make a formula, but there is "@" out of nowhere, on `=concat`, I can solve the problem with `_xlfn.`, but "@" come before another workbook link
for example, this is my formula

```
for a, b, row in zip(asd, qwe, row):
    for setoranviab2input, setoranviab2 in enumerate(range(2, 100, 1),2):
        wsprocessactive[str(b) + f'{setoranviab2}'] = f'''=IF(OR(COUNTIF({rekeningkoran}$C{setoranviab2input+6},"*"&{namatoko}''' + str(a) + f'''$51:''' + str(a) + f'''$100&"*")),"TUNAI "&''' + str(b) + f'''$1,"")'''
```

but the output

```
=IF(LEFT(setoranvia!$BE2;5)="TUNAI";"";IF(OR(COUNTIF(rekeningkoran.xlsx!$C8;"*"&@namatoko.xlsx!A$1:A$50&"*"));"TUNAI "&B$1;""))
```

I already tried not using r-string, but the output still the same

Comment: Did you check this recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76124327/how-do-i-prevent-openpyxl-from-inserting-an-when-using-summed-array-formulae) and the included google search link? There have been a few questions about this on SO.

Comment: I already try some of it, but I'm afraid I don't know the right keyword for it, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

big thanks to moken for giving me a the answer, and I'm sorry for questioning the same problem. At first I try `formula_attributes`, but the api changes to `ArrayFormula`, so here the final answer for my problem

```
wsprocessactive[str(b) + f'{setorantunaib2}'] = ArrayFormula((str(b) + f'{setorantunaib2}'),    f'''=IF(LEFT(setoranvia!$BE{setorantunaib2input},5)="TUNAI","",IF(OR(COUNTIF({rekeningkoran}$C{setorantunaib2input+6},"*"&{namatoko}''' + str(a) + f'''$1:''' + str(a) + f'''$50&"*")),"TUNAI "&''' + str(b) + f'''$1,""))''')
```